# Quotient of an ideal in Dedekind Domain is principal ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

The quotient ring $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ of a Dedekind domain by an ideal $\mathfrak{a}\ne 0$ is a principal ideal domain.

I am trying to show $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$ is principal ring. Let $\mathfrak{p}^i/\mathfrak{p}^n$ be an ideal and choose $\pi\in\mathfrak{p}\setminus\mathfrak{p}^2$. Then how I show that $\mathfrak{p}^i = \mathcal{O}\pi^i + \mathfrak{p}^n$  ?  Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is certainly not a domain unless $\mathfrak a$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 
$(\pi)^i \not\subset \mathfrak{p}^{i+1}$, but $(\pi)^i\subset \mathfrak{p}^i$.

Thus $(\pi)^i=J\cdot \mathfrak{p}^i$ for an ideal $J$ with $\mathfrak{p}\nmid J$ .

Now we have $(\pi)^i+\mathfrak{p}^{n}=\mathfrak{p}^{i}(J+\mathfrak{p}^{n-i})$. But $J$ and $\mathfrak{p}^{n-i}$  have no common prime ideal factors, thus $J+\mathfrak{p}^{n-i}=\mathcal{O}$ and we get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\mathcal O/\mathfrak p^n\simeq\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}/(\mathfrak pO_{\mathfrak p})^n.$$
What is the localisation of a Dedekind domain at a maximal ideal?

Comment: Actually my question is specific. I just want prove the fact that $\mathfrak{p}^i = \mathcal{O}\pi^i + \mathfrak{p}^n$. Also I already understand why only this step is enough to prove the entire result.

Comment: because the localization of a Dedekind domain is a discrete valuation ring, which is a PID.